# ¿Cómo ocultar un div con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web

Me he topado con un problema que no he podido solucionar.

Sucede que tengo 2 divs que contienen 2 "estrellitas" entonces una de ella se encuentra oculta y la otra visible.
Tengo estos elementos:

```
<div class="star">
     <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true" id="unsaved" onclick="SaveAndHide()"></i>
</div>
<div class="star">
     <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true" id="unsaved" onclick="SaveAndHide()"></i>
</div>

function SaveAndHide() {
   document.getElementById("unsaved").style.display = "none"; 
}
```

De modo que al presionar sobre una  se "oculte" únicamente  el que estoy presionando, ese código que tengo ahora, funciona pero solo me desaparece el primer "unsaved" que se encuentra.

He encontrado esta solución:

```
onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'"
```

Pero eso involucra ponerlo dentro de la etiqueta y la verdad la quiero separada, o sea en mi propio archivo .js, lo cual no he logrado adaptar.

Comment: si le pones a ambos unsaved la propiedad name="unsaved"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En primer lugar no deberías tener dos elementos con el mismo `id`. Pero felizmente no es necesario en este caso colocar ningún `id`.

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```js
function SaveAndHide(star) {
  star.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
div:nth-of-type(1) i {
  color: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) i {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="star">
  <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true" onclick="SaveAndHide(this)"></i>
</div>
<div class="star">
  <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true" onclick="SaveAndHide(this)"></i>
</div>
```

De esta manera le pasas a la función el `<i>` que quieres ocultar directamente sin necesidad de buscarlo en el DOM